# Rotate vtkDiskSource/vtkPolyDataMapper by Normals

Tags: python, data-visualization, vtk

I need to put multiple vtkDiskSource over the mesh surface (represented as vtkPolyDataMapper) so that the disks lay on the surface. Objects like vtkRegularPolygonSource has SetNormal method which could be used for "rotation". Also there is vtkTransform but I don't know how to calculate X,Y,Z values. Can anybody help me with that?

```
disk = vtk.vtkDiskSource()
disk.SetInnerRadius(1.0)
disk.SetOuterRadius(2.0)

<---- rotation

mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(disk.GetOutputPort())
```

Comment: Are you trying to add disks on all points of the polyData and use its normals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `vtk.Transform` to put the `vtk.DiskSource` in the proper orientation on your mesh surface.

```
disk = vtk.vtkDiskSource()
disk.SetInnerRadius(1.0)
disk.SetOuterRadius(2.0)
disk.Update()

# Assume we have the normal of the mesh surface in normal
# and the position in coords

z_axis = [0., 0., 1.]
axis = np.cross(z_axis, normal)
angle = np.arccos(n.dot(z_axis, normal))
transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
# Put the disks a bit above the mesh, otherwise they might be partially burried
transform.Translate(*(coords + 0.1 * normal))
transform.RotateWXYZ(n.degrees(angle), *axis)
transform_filter = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
transform_filter.SetTransform(transform)
transform_filter.SetInputConnection(disk.GetOutputPort())
transform_filter.Update()

diskmapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
diskmapper.SetInputConnection(transform_filter.GetOutputPort())
# Go on setting up actors
```